# Adding the first 100 integers to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am writing a program to display the first 100 integers ArrayList. It complies but nothing runs. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong. I have tried to add the first 100 integers and then display them, but once again I get a blank page. Here is what I have done.

```
   ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);

   for (Integer i : numbers)
     {
       numbers.add(i);
       System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
     }
```

Comment: What do you think `new ArrayList<Integer>(100);` does and why do you think so?

Comment: What do you think `Integer i : numbers` does and why do you think so?

Comment: And what about `numbers.add(i);`?

Answer (score 4):

The `100` argument in the `ArrayList` constructor specifies the *initial capacity* of the list. It does not mean that the actual number of the elements is `100`. See the documentation of the [`ArrayList` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)):

> Constructs an *empty list* with the specified initial capacity

Since your list is empty, the `for (Integer i : numbers)` loop will therefore execute zero times. You need to loop as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(100);

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
   numbers.add(i);
   System.out.println(numbers.get(i - 1));
}
```

`ArrayList.get(i)` gets the element at index `i`. Since the index starts at zero, the last statement in the loop body should be `numbers.get(i - 1)`.

If the numbers should start at zero (`0` to `99`), then the loop would be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   numbers.add(i);
   System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for (Integer i : numbers)` is the [enhanced-for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).  It effectively iterates over each entry contained in `numbers`, which is referenced for that iteration by `i`, and allows you to do things with respect to `i`.

Since `numbers` is empty, the loop won't run.

Further, `new ArrayList<>(100)` will set the initial capacity of the array list to 100; this is useful if you know that you don't want to incur the cost of the array list increasing its size every time it hits the limit.  It does *not* fill any values into the array list.

All you really need to do is change the enhanced-for to a normal `for` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't see how I wasn't able to catch that!

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through an empty list. You need to change you code to add values to this ArrayList, then print them out:

```
int initialSize = 100;
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(initialSize);
for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
 {
   numbers.add(i);
   System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: Ahh! nice catch... Didn't think that one through. Changed it to be correct.